# completely monotone sequence

Tags: calculus, analysis

Is the sequence $(\frac{1}{n^2})$ completely monotone$^*$?

$*$A sequence $(a_n)$ is completely monotone iff $(-1)^k(\Delta^k a)_n\geq 0$, where $(\Delta a)_n=a_{n+1}-a_n.$

Comment: What does $(\Delta^ka)$ mean @BigM?

Comment: its defined inductively e.g $(\Delta^2 a)_2=\Delta(a_3-a_2)=a_4-a_3-(a_3-a_2)$

Comment: What happens when $n=0$?

Comment: @ChamberlainFoncha   $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Comment: You mean $\mathbb{N}^+$?

Comment: In any case, is there way to monotonize a sequence which is not completely monotone?

Comment: @ChamberlainFoncha I do not know but that's a good question. I should mention that the original question essentially came from investigating a certain maximal inequality for ax+b group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put $f(x)=-\log x$ for $x\in (0,1]$. We have $f(x)\geq 0$. Now we have for $n\geq 0$ $\displaystyle \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}=\int_0^1 x^n f(x)dx$. Thus:
$$(-1)\Delta(a)(n+1)=-\int_0^1 (x^{n+1}-x^n)f(x)dx=\int_0^1 (1-x)x^n f(x)dx$$
An easy induction show that:
$$(-1)^k \Delta^k(a)(n+1)=\int_0^1 (1-x)^k x^n f(x)dx\geq 0$$ and we are done.